# How to Add a Tooltip for a Button inside Datatabels Created by Yajra Addons on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, yajra-datatable

How Can I Add a Tooltip for a Button inside the Datatables Created automatically by Yajra Addons inside Laravel?
**the following code is for html function inside the Datatable file**

```
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
                ->parameters([
                    'dom'=>'Blfrtip',
                    'lengthMenu'=>[[10,25,50,100,-1],[10,25,50,'All Records']],
                     'buttons'=>[
                         ['extend'=>'print','className'=>'btn btn-primary','text'=>'<i class="fa fa-print"></i>'],
                         ['extend'=>'csv','className'=>'btn btn-primary','text'=>'<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>'],
                     ],
        ]);
}
```